# Android First App Tutorial Issue

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get this to work, even copying and pasting the code exactly as the tutorial says it, but it doesn't seem to work. I know the issue is in MainActivity or DisplayMessageActivity, but I can't see what's wrong. I also have the DisplayMessageActivity in the same folder as MainActivity.

I get the following errors.

```
DisplayMessageActivity
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class SuppressLint
Gradle: error: package R does not exist
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable NavUtils

MainActivity
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class DisplayMessageActivity
```

I have been fiddling with this for awhile, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

What I have,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
~snip~
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
~snip~
```

DisplayMessageActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Juned and Peter were correct. The only reason it wasn't working right away was because I had messed something else up. Thanks guys!

Comment: Do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O` to arrange your imports first.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but i cant seem to find this `build.gradle` file, i am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday (:
You need to add to your `imports` in `DisplayMessageActivity`

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
```

Also, you need to add to your `build.gradle` file in `dependencies` section:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
```

About Support Libraries you can red [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: That worked, thank you! Now my only problem is

    Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class DisplayMessageActivity

It's in the right folder, is a class and is spelled correctly. For some reason it isn't being acknowledged. It's acting like it isn't in the manifest, but it is?

Comment: What IDE do you use? I had a problem with Android Studio, which solved by restarting the IDE. Android Studio isn't stable yet. Also, show your full manifest file.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but i cant seem to find this `build.gradle` file, i am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the imports for `SuppressLint` in your DisplayMessageActivity class. Add the correct imports.

Also not that `SuppressLint` annotation was added in API level 16. Make sure that you are using build SDK to 16 or higher.

Comment: I am using build SDK 17+. The import for SupressLint did make that error go away!

I still get; package R does not exist, cannot find symbol variable NavUtils and cannot find symbol class DisplayMessageActivity (from MainActivity).

I tried Googling this stuff before making this topic but couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your issue is that you don't have 'package com.example.firstapp;' at the top of DisplayMessageActivity.java.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Android first app documentiaont they have clearly mentioned as below. The Note near the ***

> Build an Intent topic , Step 1

---

> Note: The reference to DisplayMessageActivity will raise an error if
>   you’re using an IDE such as Android Studio because the class doesn’t
>   exist yet. Ignore the error for now; you’ll create the class soon.

Therefore, if you scroll down more in the documentation you can find the topic ***Create the Second Activity*** that create the new DisplayMessageActivity.

[Android First App Tutorial By Google](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `activity_display_message.xml`

```
android:id="@+id/activity_display_message">
```